# Sheaf Hom between locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I stumbled upon a question in Vakil's notes which asks us to prove that for two locally free sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ each of finite rank, the sheaf $\mathcal{Hom_O(F,G)}$ is locally free with rank equal to the product of the ranks of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$. I reduced the question to $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ being free of rank 1.  Now,  my plan was to give a map $$\mathcal{Hom_O(O,O)}\to \mathcal{O}$$ and show that the stalks are isomorphic. The map is over a section U  is $$\phi \mapsto \phi(U)(1)$$
However, I am not sure  if this is correct since this proves that dual of a locally free sheaf is isomorphic to itself which is not true. Also, proving the stalk part does  not seem to be easy. Any other ideas of proving this lemma would be very helpful.

Comment: Reduce to the affine case; then you're just proving the Yoneda lemma for commutative rings.

Comment: Vakil made a comment in his text saying the lemma holds for ringed spaces in general.

Comment: You can show that the map $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})\to \mathcal{O}$ you wrote is an isomorphism directly, without using stalks (in the other direction, the map is $s\mapsto m_s$ where $m_s$ is the multiplication by $s$). It does not prove that the dual of a locally free sheaf is isomorphic to itself, just that the dual of a locally free sheaf is locally isomorphic to itself (which is obvious). But these local isomorphisms usually don't glue.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}, \{V_i\}_{j \in J}$ be covers of $X$ such that
$$\mathcal F|_{U_i} \cong \mathcal O_{U_i}^{\oplus m}, \quad \mathcal G|_{V_j} \cong \mathcal O_{V_j}^{\oplus n}.$$

Then $\{U_i \cap V_j\}_{i\in I, j \in J}$ is a cover of $X$ such that
$$\mathcal F|_{U_i \cap V_j} \cong \mathcal O_{U_i \cap V_j}^{\oplus m}, \quad \mathcal G|_{U_i \cap V_j} \cong \mathcal O_{U_i \cap V_j}^{\oplus n}.$$

For any open $W \subset U_i \cap V_j$,
$$\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal F, \mathcal G)(W)=\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal F|_{W}, \mathcal G|_{W})\cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_{W}^{\oplus m},\mathcal O_{W}^{\oplus n}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_{W},\mathcal O_{W})^{\oplus mn} \cong \mathcal O_W^{\oplus mn}.$$

So, $$\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal F, \mathcal G)|_{U_i \cap V_j} \cong \mathcal O_{U_i \cap V_j}^{\oplus mn}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** There is a canonical isomorphism (HH.Ex.II.5.1)

$$\phi: E^*\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}F \cong Hom_{\mathcal{O}}(E,F)   ,$$

and since $E^*$ is locally free (of the same rank as $E$) it follows $E^*\otimes F$ is locally free of rank $ef$ with $e:=rk(E),f:=rk(F)$

**Note:** The map $\phi$ is a "vector bundle version" of the map of vector spaces

$$\psi: V^*\otimes_k W \cong Hom_k(V,W)$$

defined by

$$\psi(f\otimes w)(v):=f(v)w.$$

**General principle** "Most" intrinsic maps of vector spaces globalize to locally free sheaves.